# Question about rotatebox and xy pic

Tags: xy-pic

I have the following question:

I have heard that you can use $\xymatrix@1...$, if you want to put diagrams not into a separate line, but into the line you are writing text at the very moment.

This does work, but unfortunately not in the following example...

The problem is that I get error messages because of the `\rotatebox` command, when I put the lines below in the form `$\xymatrix@1...$...`

...but it works, if I use the `\begin{xy}...` environment, as I did it below. Unfortunately, then my triangle is placed in the middle of a new separate line.

Does anybody have an idea, how to prevent this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{extpfeil}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[arrow, matrix, curve]{xy}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pzc}


\deffootnotemark{[\thefootnotemark]}
\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{[\thefootnotemark]}}

\begin{document}

\noindent Ist $\xymatrix@1{{A\ \ } \ar@{{>}->}[r]^f &  B }$ ein Monomorphismus, so erhalten wir: 

$$
\begin{xy}

\xymatrix@1{{A\ \ } \ar@{{>}->}[rr]^f \ar@{->}[rd]_{\rotatebox{330}{$\sim$}} &  &  B \\ &  Im f \ar@{^{(}->}[ru]^n & }

\end{xy}
$$


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: I get no error when using the `$\xymatrix@1...$` form, with `\rotatebox`. The `xy` environment is not necessary; use `\[...\]` rather than `$$...$$` in LaTeX and never leave a blank line before a displayed math formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get no error on your code as posted or changed as below which is how I think you described changing it. Please edit your question to make an example that generates the error and say exactly what error you get. You may also consider making your example more minimal by removuing most of the packages if they are not needed to show the error.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{extpfeil}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[arrow, matrix, curve]{xy}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pzc}


\deffootnotemark{[\thefootnotemark]}
\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{[\thefootnotemark]}}

\begin{document}

\noindent Ist $\xymatrix@1{{A\ \ } \ar@{{>}->}[r]^f &  B }$ ein Monomorphismus, so erhalten wir: 

$
%$$\begin{xy}
\xymatrix@1{{A\ \ } \ar@{{>}->}[rr]^f \ar@{->}[rd]_{\rotatebox{330}{$\sim$}} &  &  B \\ &  Im f \ar@{^{(}->}[ru]^n & }
%\end{xy}$$
$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works now. I think it did not work the way I typed it, because I made a few typing mistakes, but copying and pasting your code works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @BernhardBoehmler On that basis, I've closed the question as 'too localized'.